# Is milk meat or a vegetable?

Tags: rimworld

For making fine meals, does milk count as a vegetable or as meat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After testing with the developer tools, milk can be used as meat when cooking.

On a blank map, I spawned milk and potatoes and colonists started cooking the meal. I also tested with milk and meat but it didn't work.

So milk does count a meat in the game.

EDIT: I also looked at the recipe definitions and the food category in the game files. Fine meals require items from the categories MeatRaw or AnimalProductRaw, and PlantFoodRaw. Milk is categorized as AnimalProductRaw.